# ASP.Net Identity (2.2.1) Cookie on different webapps in same host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

I need to change the name of the cookie when the user switch application. For that, I have change the cookie name option, like in [Asp.Net Identity and cookie names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038303/asp-net-identity-and-cookie-names).

But unfortunatly, no cookie is sent to the browser so the user never authenticate, I don't know why and I'm out of ideas...

Here's the code in ConfigureOAuth:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),                
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {                    
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<IMS_UserManager, IMS_User, int>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                getUserIdCallback: (claim) => int.Parse(claim.GetUserId()))
    },
    CookieDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityCookieURL"].ToString()
    CookieName = ".Asp.Net." + AuthenticationCookieName,
    CookieHttpOnly = true
});
```

What Am I doing wrong ? (AuthenticationCookieName is "IMS", so no fancy characters in it).

Thank you,

PS: The WebApps are all in localhost but with different ports (running in the IDE, but in production they would be on a intranet server, with the same config) ...

PS2: The problem really is on the line `CookieName = ".Asp.Net." + AuthenticationCookieName,`, because when I remove it, it works like a charm... 
`HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated` return always false and with chrome there's no cookie in 'localhost'...

Comment: Have you tried removing the full stops (periods) from the cookie name?

Comment: Changed to `CookieName = "AspNetCookieName"`, still the same

Comment: Looking at further doco I can see it should be fine with periods, anyway

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you are running the sites on localhost:xxx, I don't believe that will work when you are trying to set the cookie domain to something totally different (imagine the security vulnerabilities if you could).

You should set the cookie domain to whatever your base domain is, and do the same in all the apps that you want to share it across, eg:

```
CookieDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityCookieURL"].ToString()
```

So in production you may set the app setting value to ims.com but in dev set it to localhost (you could use a web.config transform for this difference in environments)

Comment: Thanks Bron Squire for pointing out this line, you are totally right, but that don't help me with my problem (I have edited my question to be more precise). If I remove totally CookieDomain, the result is the same :(