# base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext) is allways false - how to find the reason

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

Hi I'm trying to use a custom authorize attribute but base.AuthorizeCore allways return false. I have no idea where I've done mistake. Could you tell me where is the problem please. My AuthorizeAttribute:

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }
        string roles = string.Join("", httpContext.Session["UserRole"]);
       // string roles = string.Join("", HttpContext.Current.Session["UserRole"]);
        if (Roles.Contains(roles))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My LogIn method:

```
 public ActionResult LogIn()
 {
        var model = new UserModel();
        return View(model);
 }


 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult LogIn(UserModel model)
 {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("LogIn", model);
        }
        else
            {
            var usermodelDB = _UserAccountService.GetUser(model.Password);
            if (model.userName == usermodelDB.userName && model.Password==usermodelDB.Password)
            {


                model.userRole = usermodelDB.userRole;
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.userRole, true);
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserRole"] = usermodelDB.userRole;
                var ia =System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }
            return View("LogIn", model);
        }
 }
```

and the method with limited access:

```
[AuthorizeUser(Roles="User")]
public ActionResult Index(int page=0)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the user is not in that role. `AuthorizeCore` look at the user's identity and test which roles the user is in. So it returns true if the user is authorized. ([+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore(v=vs.118).aspx))

Comment: thanks, role taken from Db was "User    " and the role in the attribute was "User"

Answer (score 0):

For me, I deleted the cookies of website then it worked. Seems that two applications where using the same db table for storing users. Chaning the cookie name helped to to solve the error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25039278/7429464